# Can not use source in report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, oledb, sap-ase

Environment:

Win 2008 R2 64bit

MS SQL 2014

Sybase PC Client 64 bit

I created Source for Sybase ASE 15.7 in Reporting Services using OLE DB String

```
Server=SERVER_NAME;Provider=ASEOLEDB.15.7.0.1212;Port=5000;Catalog=rp1;
```

When I press Test Connection button it tells me that connection established.

Next in reporting builder I choose this source and again press Test Connection button and it again tells me that Connection created successfully.

Then I press Next button enter creadentials for this connection and when I press "OK" button I get the message

> The 'ASEOLEDB.15.7.0.1212' provider is not registered on the local machine

How can it be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I don`t why, but if I use this string Provider=ASEOLEDB.1;Data Source=SERVER_NAME,5000;Initial Catalog=rp1 everything is ok.